# ¿Por que no se da ni un punto de reputacion al usuario autor de un comentario marcado como util?

Tags: soporte

Tengo poco tiempo aquí y quizás me pase por alto una lectura en donde lo digan, pero me da curiosidad el por que al obtener un voto en un comentario no se asignan puntos de reputación.

Comment: Los comentarios en la red son considerados como algo no esencial, de hecho se avisa específicamente de que pueden ser eliminados sin previo aviso. Dado este carácter accesorio, no tiene mucho sentido puntuar ni positiva ni negativamente a los comentarios.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para dejar una respuesta, y casi copiando lo que dijo Pikoh, los comentarios son solo eso, comentarios.

Por lo tanto, mas allá que se puedan puntuar positivamente, para dar mas énfasis al mismo, no cuentan como puntos de reputación, ya que son volátiles.

No se supone que respondan la pregunta. Entonces como pueden ser eliminados en cualquier momento, no dan reputación.